# Where is build version info in 2.90, if not on the Splash Screen?

Tags: interface

Earlier, I used to click on the Blender icon > Splash screen to get build info, build times, hash etc.

It is not on the splash screen anymore. It only shows major version.

Where can I find the info ?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the App (icon) menu > About Blender.